# FlinkDeployment calculated derived memory wrong

Tags: apache-flink

One of my flinkdeployment failed to start with error:

```
Derived JVM Overhead size (1.338gb (1436549120 bytes)) is not in configured JVM Overhead range [192.000mb (201326592 bytes), 1024.000mb (1073741824 bytes)]
```

However, my current setting for the job is

```
flinkConfiguration:
    jobmanager.memory.heap.size: 350mb
    jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 200mb
    taskmanager.memory.heap.size: 200mb
    taskmanger.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 160mb
taskManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 5
      memory: 4gb
jobManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 2gb
```

Others are using the default value, namely that the derived memory should be
total process memory (4g) * taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.fraction (default 0.1) = 0.4g

I am so confused how this ended up derived to 1.338gb? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: manually tested the spec, and noticed that the issue seems related to `jobmanager.memory.heap.size`   If Ieft unset, everything works as expected. But if I keep it configured, no matter what the value is, it will always show the derived memory error